# How to write IF/ELSE statements on Google Sheets with multiple formulas?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, multiple-conditions

I am trying to convert multiple currency entries automatically on Google Sheets.

Currently storing INR in Column B, USD in Column C and SGD in Column D. I want any value entered in either Columns B or C for any given row to be automatically converted to the corresponding SGD value.

This is the general logic on Google Sheets I have been trying to apply on cell D3 as follows,

```
If ISBLANK(C3) = true {
Convert currency in cell B3 from INR to SGD
} else {
Convert currency in cell C3 from USD to SGD
}
```

I have been trying the `IFS` formula, been playing around with different inputs and parameters but keep ending up with parsing errors. Would appreciate any help on this as this is my first time. Here is a snippet of one of my attempts.

`=IFS(ISBLANK(C3), (B3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:INRSGD")),(C3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDSGD"))))`

Answer (score 1):

`IF` version:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C3),B3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:INRSGD"),C3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDSGD"))
```

[image]

`IFS` would work like this:

```
=IFS(NOT(ISBLANK(B3)),B3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:INRSGD"),NOT(ISBLANK(C3)),C3*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:USDSGD"))
```

[image]